# Access-Control-Allow-Origin / Plupload HTML5 / Cross-Domain / DMcloud

Tags: html, cross-domain, plupload

I'm implementing a video website with [Dailymotion Cloud](http://www.dmcloud.net/) and [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) (HTML5 runtime).

The workflow is :

1. Retrieve upload URL via dmcloud API
2. POST file to this URL
3. Retrieve the JSON data in response in order to display the video

I'm issuing the following on the upload : `xmlhttprequest cannot load origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin`

My issue is that the upload fails with some upload URLs, in a non-deterministic way. When an upload URL works, it works as many times as I want, and when an upload URL doesn't, it never works.

The Dmcloud server sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.
Each request is done in two times : first an `OPTION` request is sent to ensure that the URL is accepting origin. And then a `POST` request is done.

`OPTION` requests ever successed, with good headers, the issue is coming at the end of the `POST` request...

Do you think that it is a Dmcloud server issue ? A chrome HTML5 issue ? A plupload issue ?

Some network screenshots :

**Success: OPTIONS request**
[image: Success: OPTIONS request]

**Success: POST request**
[image: Success: POST request]

**Fail: OPTIONS request**
[image: Fail: OPTIONS request]

**Fail: POST request**
[image: Fail: POST request]

Comment: Do you know if the failed POST request actually hits your server? If so, do you have the content of how your server responds? You can use a tool like Wireshark to see the actual network traffic. My initial guess is that the failed POST request is missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, but its tough to say without seeing the network traces and the response.

Comment: @monsur OK I think you're right... I've no time to do packet sniffing but I've found a common factor between all the failed requests : the target server is `upload-02.dmcloud.net` (_good_ urls are on `upload-01`). So this is definitely a server-side error, I'll open a ticket on dmcloud. Thanks for your time ! (make an answer if you want to claim your points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a server-side issue : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header was not sent on `upload-02.dmcloud.net`.

The awesome guys of the Dmcloud support team solved this very quickly.

Thanks to @monsur, who helps me identifying the issue.